# JBPM Deadlines with Multi Instance

Tags: jbpm, deadlines

We are using JBPM multi-instance subprocess, where parallel tasks are created within a subprocess. When deadlines (SLA due and delay) are configured for these parallel tasks (they are instances of the same task in the underlying template), once one of the tasks is completed, the deadlines of other pending tasks are not executed. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: is it possible to share bpmn process ? It will be easy to troubleshoot.